# JQuery dropdown box behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, the user can hover over the area and a drop down box appears. 
The user wants the box to disappear if the user clicks somewhere on the screen. Is there a way to accomplish this using JavaScript and jQuery?

Code below ... thank you in advance for your response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".password").fancybox({
            'width': 500,
            'height': 260,
            'autoScale': false,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'type': 'iframe'
        });



        // Login drop down
        $(".signin").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".signin_menu").show();
            $(".signin").addClass("menu-open");
        });
        $(".signin_menu").hover(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".signin_menu").show();
            $(".signin").addClass("menu-open");
        });
```

Comment: somewhere on the screen or somewhere else on the screen ?

Comment: When the drop down appears you could put an invisible div in the background that spans the entire width and height of the page and if the user clicks on it then the drop down disappears... its essential the same method that light box plugins use. There is the opaque black background and if you double click it the lightbox goes away.

Comment: It would be nice if jquery had a `clickOutside` method or something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
$('html').on('click', function() {
    $('.signin_menu:visible').hide();
});

$('.signin_menu > *').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

If a user clicks on an element outside of the .signin_menu, the .signin_menu will be hidden.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help!! I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The function .hover() can have more than 1 parameter (http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

If you put a second parameter, it will add a "hoverOut" handler.

Try this:

```
$(".signin").hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".signin_menu").show();
        $(".signin").addClass("menu-open");
    },function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".signin_menu").hide();
        $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
    });
    $(".signin_menu").hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".signin_menu").show();
        $(".signin").addClass("menu-open");
    },function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".signin_menu").hide();
        $(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
    });
```

The first function is HoverIn, the second HoverOut.
That way, the dropdown will disappear after you put your mouse out of the box.

Comment: From how the question reads I don't think he wants the menu to disappear when you hover out.

Comment: Thank you, but the user doesn't want the box to disappear when you move the mouse... this was the first modification I made, and then the user (who I feel is being difficult) wants the box to stay unless he clicks on his screen. There may not be anything to be done here. Thanks you!!